# R. Meir and Reish Lakish on Gan Eden and Gehinnom

Tags: sin, story-identification, gan-eden, gehinnom

I remember reading humble statements by both R. Meir and Reish Lakish, saying about themselves that they would probably need to go through Gehinnom to some degree, because of unknown sins and shortcomings. I can't seem to find the source now though. Do you know where it is?